# Why Laravel Sanctum returns unauthenticated?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I am developing a Vue SPA. I am using Vue as frontend, Laravel 7 as backend for api and **Laravel Sanctum** for authentication.
When I execute the command "npm run serve" in Vue root directory I see the following lines.

App running at:

- Local:   http://localhost:8080/
- Network: http://192.168.0.100:8080/

Everything is working fine when I use the Local URL  http://localhost:8080.
In that case I use the following setup:

URL to login from Vue frontend:  http://localhost:80/cpa_labour_management_api/api/login

In sanctum.php file in Laravel config folder : 'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1')),

In session.php file in Laravel config folder : 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

****But when I use the Network URL http://192.168.0.100:8080 then it returns unauthenticated error (401).
In that case I use the following setup:**

URL to login from Vue frontend:  http://192.168.0.100:80/cpa_labour_management_api/api/login

In sanctum.php file in Laravel config folder : 'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1,http://192.168.0.100:8080')),

In session.php file in Laravel config folder : 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'http://192.168.0.100:8080'),

**I want to access the SPA from other devices within same LAN. So I need to use the url http://192.168.0.100:8080 instead of http://localhost:8080.** I don't understand why it is happening. Please help me with your suggestion what can I do.

Comment: Remove `http://` from env entry. This is not a part of domain.

Comment: @Harven I remove http:// from env and now I am using 192.168.0.100:8080 in env but same problem.